# I need some clarification with the concept of depth/stencil buffers in direct3D 11 (c++)

Tags: c++, direct3d, direct3d11

I am following tutorials online to help me create my first game, and so far, i am understanding every concept that Direct3D 11 has to throw at me.

But there's a certain concept that i can't seem to completely grasp yet; the depth/stencil buffers.

I understand that a depth/stencil buffers are used to "compare" the depths of pixels from different objects in a game. If two objects are overlapping each other, then the object that has less depth in the pixels will show up closer to the camera. And you define a depth/stencil buffer by filling out the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC..

But my question is; if i fill out the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC structure, then am i telling directX **HOW** to compare the pixels of different objects in a game?

If you don't understand my question, please just try to explain the concept of depth/stencil buffers as simple as you can. Also please try to explain what exactly am i defining by filling out the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC structure

Thank you.

Comment: From the documentation, it looks like `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC` is used to describe the content and layout of the texture. As in it tells Direct3D how to read the texture. The width, height, color channels, how many bits per color channel, and the order they're in (RGBA, BGRA, RGB no A, BGR no A, stored in float? Maybe unsigned int? etc)

Comment: I'm learning OpenGL on my own at the moment, so I could be very wrong. But what I understand is that the depth buffer helps determine which pixel will be shown in the final image. If you have polygons overlapping, and the one behind is drawn first, then when the other polygons draw, its depth value will be compared with the depth value from the previous polygon. If it's on top then that pixel gets written into the color buffer. Else the result just gets discarded

Comment: So no, if you fill out the description structure, you're telling Direct3D how to read and store the result (How many bits, what data type). Now how to compare it. I don't know what the equivalent is for D3D, but in OpenGL, there's `glDepthFunc()` that can change how OpenGL compares depth values. You can set it to `GL_LESS`, `GL_GREATER` etc. Here's MS's documentation on Depth-stencil buffers. It seems they use a `D3D11_COMPARISON_FUNC` enum: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb205074%28v=vs.85%29.aspx I think this may be the equivalent to `glDepthFunc()`

Comment: I still don't understand why I need to fill out the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC structure just to create a depth/stencil buffer. What relevance does this structure have with a depth/stencil buffer? For example, if i assign 300 to the Width member and 300 to the height member, then am i telling direct3D to "compare" the depth of all 300 pixels in the height and width of the screen?

Comment: You need to fill it out because the depth/stencil buffers are essentially textures. Arrays of pixels/color data. An image. By filling it out you're specifying how much space the graphics card needs to allocate for that buffer, and how many bits a depth/pixel value takes up. The GPU needs to know that in order to know where in memory a pixel for position (x, y) is. It specifies the layout of the buffer

Comment: Hmm can you explain to me the purpose of some of the members in the D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC structure in relevance to the depth/stencil buffer? I mean, if i set 300 to the members "Width" and "Height", what exactly does that do to the depth stencil buffer? (Some of the documentation for the structures can be a bit vague..so i need someone to explain this to me in different words)

Comment: it doesn't do anything until you pass the structure into `CreateTexture2D()`. Then the GPU allocates memory to hold that texture. By setting the width and height to 300, it tells D3D that there's 90,000 pixels in that buffer. By setting the format to say `DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UINT`, you indicate that the pixels are 32 bits. first 8 bits for red, then the next 8 are green, then blue, then alpha, all represented as an unsigned int. Multiply that by 90,000, a 360,000 byte buffer is created in your GPU's VRAM for that texture

Comment: What each member is supposed to represent is documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: Ok I understand now. But I have one more question, When the GPU allocates memory by setting 90,000 pixels to the depth/stencil buffer(by calling CreateTexture2D()).. what does the depth stencil buffer do with the pixels? does it use the pixels to compare the depth values of each pixel in the images?

Comment: It should store the z component of a pixel. Like I said before, if two polygons are overlapping, and the one behind the other is being drawn, those pixels will have a higher z value because it'll be further away from the camera in the z axis in Normalized Device Coordinates. Then when the polygon in front is being drawn, its pixels will replace the other polygon's pixels because they will have a lower z value. And the corresponding depth values will be overwritten too. Basically it stores the lowest z value of a pixel because the lower the z value, the closer the surface is to the camera

Answer (score 2):

When you fill out the `D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`, you are describing the depth/stencil buffer itself: How large is it, what format does it use, how you want to bind it to the pipeline.

The 'boiler-plate' construction for this is as follows (taken from [Direct3D Win32 Game Visual Studio template](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2015/01/06/direct3d-win32-game-visual-studio-template.aspx) using the C++ equivalent `CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC`

```
CD3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC depthStencilDesc(depthBufferFormat,
    backBufferWidth, backBufferHeight, 1, 1,
    D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL);

ComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> depthStencil;
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateTexture2D(&depthStencilDesc, nullptr,
       depthStencil.GetAddressOf()));
```

The *depthBufferFormat* is determined by what level of precision you want, whether or not you are using a stencil-buffer, and your [Direct3D Feature Level](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/06/20/direct3d-feature-levels.aspx). The template uses `DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT` by default which works on all feature leaves and provides reasonable precision for depth and an 8-bit stencil. The size must exactly match your color back-buffer.

You bind the depth-stencil buffer to the render pipeline by creating a 'view' for the buffer.

```
CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_VIEW_DESC depthStencilViewDesc(D3D11_DSV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D);
DX::ThrowIfFailed(
    m_d3dDevice->CreateDepthStencilView(depthStencil.Get(),
         &depthStencilViewDesc, m_depthStencilView.ReleaseAndGetAddressOf()));
```

You then 'clear' the view each frame and then bind the view for rendering:

```
m_d3dContext->ClearDepthStencilView(m_depthStencilView.Get(),
    D3D11_CLEAR_DEPTH | D3D11_CLEAR_STENCIL, 1.0f, 0);

m_d3dContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, m_renderTargetView.GetAddressOf(),
   m_depthStencilView.Get());
```

You tell Direct3D *how* to do the comparison with `D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC` (or the C++ equivalent `D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC`).

The 'default' depth/stencil state is:

```
DepthEnable = TRUE;
DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
StencilEnable = FALSE;
StencilReadMask = D3D11_DEFAULT_STENCIL_READ_MASK;
StencilWriteMask = D3D11_DEFAULT_STENCIL_WRITE_MASK;

const D3D11_DEPTH_STENCILOP_DESC defaultStencilOp =
    { D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP,
      D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP,
      D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP,
      D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS };

FrontFace = defaultStencilOp;
BackFace = defaultStencilOp;
```

In the [DirectX Tool Kit](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=248929), we provide three common depth states:

```
// DepthNone
CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC desc(default);
desc.DepthEnable = FALSE;
desc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ZERO;
desc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;

// DepthDefault
CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC desc(default);
desc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;

// DepthRead
CD3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC desc(default);
desc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ZERO;
desc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS_EQUAL;
```

Comment: I suppose this info is up to date for d3d11. But could you please elaborate a bit on what "DepthNone", "DepthDefault" and "DepthRead" signify?

Comment: These were the states defined by the original XNA Game Studio framework. ``DepthNone`` is for when you are not using a depth-buffer at all for rendering, ``DepthDefault`` is the usual mode for using a depth-buffer for hidden-surface removal (i.e. reject if pixel is behind, update depth-buffer if you are in front), and ``DepthRead`` is for using a depth-buffer but not updating it (i.e. reject if pixel is behind) typically for translucent pixels. All three assume you are NOT using a stencil  buffer.